# Play Framework Mysql Connection, avoid exception when database is not connected

Tags: mysql, database, scala, jdbc

I have seen a lot of questions on how to connect to a database using jdbc with Play Framework 2.x with scala on stack overflow, and I finally managed to configure it correctly for a mysql database.

My problem is different, as I want to avoid an exception triggered on first connection :

```
[info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'mysql'
[error] application - 

! @72aoamohb - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [mysql]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:806)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:48)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.connect(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:72)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:62)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:58)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Failed to initialize pool: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
    at play.api.PlayConfig.reportError(Configuration.scala:996)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:70)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:123)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:138)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:44)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:512)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:105)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:58)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:123)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:958)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1038)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:339)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2247)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2100)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2084)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:214)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:298)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2247)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2100)
```

Here is my configuration file :

```
db {

  # You can declare as many datasources as you want.
  # By convention, the default datasource is named `default`

  # Mysql database configuration
  mysql.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  mysql.username = "root"
  mysql.password = "pass"
  mysql.schema = "DBCOMPARATOR_DEFAULT"
  mysql.port = "3306"
  mysql.url="jdbc:mysql://"${general.hostname}":"${db.mysql.port}"/"${db.mysql.schema}"?autoReconnect=true"

}
```

When my Mysql database is up and running and the schema is ready, everything works correctly and my app launches. However, I would like to avoid this exception when my database is not running on application startup.

When this is done, is it possible to reconnect to the database and do requests as if the database was never down in the first place ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Matt.

Comment: So you basically want to start a database server from a web application. Uhmmmmm.........

Comment: The point is To be able to start and connect to several databases at the same time. It's ok for a database to be down as I Can restart it manually (This is not going to production soon). I just want to avoid that kind of exception that crashes my app even if the database is not needed. Not sure if this is clearer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer seems pretty simple after all. If you want to avoid an error launching your web application with a stopped mysql database (Or any other), don't use Play default configuration, but choose to do it with classic jdbc connection, directly in your controller.

Here is my configuration file :

```
libraryDependencies += jdbc

general.hostname = "localhost"

# ----------- Custom db configuration for "manual" jdbc connections
custom.db {
  # -- Mysql jdbc configuration
  mysql.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  mysql.username = "root"
  mysql.password = "pass"
  mysql.schema = "DBCOMPARATOR_DEFAULT"
  mysql.port = "3306"
  mysql.options = "autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10"
  mysql.url="jdbc:mysql://"${general.hostname}":"${custom.db.mysql.port}"/"${custom.db.mysql.schema}"?"${custom.db.mysql.options}
}
```

I defined "custom.db" myself so that Play does not consider it as default database configuration. 
Now, here is my controller code (Not bug proof as it does not test all configuration variables effective presence) :

```
import java.sql.{DriverManager, Connection}
import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}

/**
  * Created by msb on 08/12/16.
  */
class DatabasesController @Inject() (configuration : Configuration) extends Controller {

  def mysql_connection_test = Action {
    val driver : Option[String] = configuration.getString("custom.db.mysql.driver")
    val url : Option[String] = configuration.getString("custom.db.mysql.url")
    val username : Option[String] = configuration.getString("custom.db.mysql.username")
    val password : Option[String] = configuration.getString("custom.db.mysql.password")

    var connection : Option[Connection] = None
    try {
      Class.forName(driver.get)
      connection = Some(DriverManager.getConnection(url.get, username.get, password.get))

      System.out.println(connection)

    } catch {
      case e : Exception => e.printStackTrace()
    }

    Ok("Still has to be tested")
  }
}
```

I took it from this tutorial : [Alvin Alexander scala documentation and examples](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-connect-mysql-database-scala-jdbc-select-query)

I also thought about using Filters to catch the exception, but it did not seem clean enough. This code can still be improved, using classes for example.

Hope this can help anyone going through the same problem.